# Getting "borrowed value does not live long enough" Error While Trying to Pass a Boxed dyn Trait into a Function

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I get really confused by the behavior of the borrow checker.

```
trait Foo {
  fn foo(&self);
}

struct Bar<'a> {
  pub f : &'a Vec<i32>
}

impl<'a> Foo for Bar<'a> {
  fn foo(&self) {
    for i in self.f {
      println!("{}", i);
    }
  }
}

fn call(b : &Box<dyn Foo>) {
  b.foo();
}

fn main() {
  let a = vec!(1,2,3);
  let b : Box<dyn Foo> = Box::new(Bar {f : &a});
  call(&b)
}
```

By compiling this piece of code I get:

```
error[E0597]: `a` does not live long enough
  --> main.rs:23:44
   |
23 |   let b : Box<dyn Foo> = Box::new(Bar {f : &a});
   |                          ------------------^^--
   |                          |                 |
   |                          |                 borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                          cast requires that `a` is borrowed for `'static`
24 |   call(&b)
25 | }
   | - `a` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Could someone explain to me why in this case `a` does not live long enough? It seems to me that it will live through the entire life cycle of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `Box<dyn Foo>` means `Box<dyn Foo + 'static>`, so only `'static` values can be stored in `Box<dyn Foo>`.  `a` is created inside a function, so it does not live for `'static`.

You can adjust the lifetime by using a lifetime parameter:

```
fn call<'a>(b: &Box<dyn Foo + 'a>) {
    b.foo();
}
```

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03b34b9c8a438b866d385ae30d5366e6))

Comment: The parameter should be `b: &Box<dyn Foo + 'a>`. No need to force the reference to have the same lifetime.

Comment: You can go further and make it `fn call(b: &Box<dyn Foo + '_>)`

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `main` function is not "the entire cycle of the program". There is some initialization code that is run before `main` gets called, and some teardown code that is run after it returns. So the Rust compiler does not handle `main` differently from any other function.

In your case, since you don't specify it explicitly, the compiler assumes that the parameter to `call` is a reference to a `Box<dyn Foo +'static>`. You can override this by specifying the lifetime yourself:

```
fn call<'a>(b: &Box<dyn Foo + 'a>) {
    b.foo();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f74e8dca1a952d8fe448def14d3cb029)